# Every reflection is an isometry proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry, reflection

The theorem is that every reflection $R_{S}$ in an affine subspace $S$ of $\mathbb{E}^{n}$ is an isometry:

$R_S:\ \mathbb{E}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{E}^{n}:\ x \mapsto R_{S}(x) = x + 2 \overrightarrow{x\pi_{S}(x)}$

I'm horrendously stuck with the proof.
I get that I'm trying to prove that $R_{S}$ preserves the distance between the two points, but I'm lost as to how.

EDIT:

$\pi_{S}(x)$ is defined as the intersection of $S$ and the euclidean subspace $T_x$ through $x$, perpendicular to $S$.

Comment: What's $\pi_S(x)$.... how is it defined?

Comment: A brute force method would be taking an orthonormal system of reference and calculating the formula for the reflection. Then calculate distances and they should be the same.

Comment: I tried that, and it seems that's what my textbook is trying to encourage me to do, but it doesn't seem to work out for me. The book just skips to the end result :(

Comment: I don't really have time for a full answer right now (it's late here) but if it hasn't been answered by tommorow I will write one. For now the hint: taking an appropriate reference you should find that the formula is basically $(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)\mapsto (-x_1,\dots,-x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)$. Careful though, the distance won't necessarily be the familiar formula in this reference, you'll have to calculate it with the inner product matrix.

Comment: I have found the answer, I think.
Should I post it myself?

Comment: Absolutely. It's best if you figure it out for yourself!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{u_1,\dotsc,u_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $T_x$.
Now pick a point $p$ on $S$.
$\pi_S(x)$ can then be written as follows:
$$ \pi_S(x)$ = x + \sum_{i=1}^k ((p-x) \cdot u_i)u_i$$

For all points $x$ and $y$ of $\mathbb{E}^n$, watch what happens to the distance:

First (for simplicity later), I will work out the vector between the reflection of $x$ and the reflection of $y$.

$$      \begin{array}{rll}
        R_{S}(x) - R_{S}(y) &= (x + 2\overrightarrow{x\pi_{S}(x)}) - (y + 2\overrightarrow{y\pi_{S}(y)}) &\\
                           &= (x + 2(\pi_{S}(x) - x)) - (y + 2(\pi_{S}(y) - y)) &\\
                           &= (-x + 2\pi_{S}(x)) - (-y + 2\pi_{S}(y)) &\\
                           &= (-x + 2(x + \sum_{i=1}^{k}((p-x)\cdot u_{i})u_{i})) - (-y + 2(y + \sum_{i=1}^{k}((p-y)\cdot u_{i})u_{i})) &\\
                           &= (x + 2\sum_{i=1}^{k}((p-x)\cdot u_{i})u_{i}) - (y + 2\sum_{i=1}^{k}((p-y)\cdot u_{i})u_{i}) &\\
                           &= (x-y) + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((p-x)\cdot u_{i})u_{i} -  \sum_{i=1}^{k}((p-y)\cdot u_{i})u_{i}\right) &\\
                           &= (x-y) + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(((p-x)\cdot u_{i})u_{i} - ((p-y)\cdot u_{i})u_{i}\right)\right) &\\
                           &= (x-y) + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left((((p-x)\cdot u_{i})- ((p-y)\cdot u_{i}))u_{i}\right)\right) &\\
                           &= (x-y) + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}(((p-x)-(p-y))\cdot u_{i} )u_{i}\right) &\\
                           &= (x-y) + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((y-x)\cdot u_{i} )u_{i}\right) &\\
                           &= (x-y) - 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )u_{i}\right) &\\
      \end{array}$$
Now we will look at the quadrate of the distance betwee the reflection of the points:
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
        d(R_{S}(x),R_{S}(y))^2 &= \left\| R_{S}(x) - R_{S}(y)\right\|^{2} & \\
                            &= (R_{S}(x) - R_{S}(y))^{2} &\\
                            &= \left((x-y) - 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )u_{i}\right)\right)^{2} &\\
                            &= (x-y)^{2} -4(x-y)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )u_{i}\right) + 4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )u_{i}\right)^{2} &\\
                            &= (x-y)^{2} -4(x-y)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}u_{i}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )\right) + 4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )u_{i}\right)^{2} &\\
                            &= (x-y)^{2} -4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y) \cdot u_{i})\cdot((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )\right) + 4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )u_{i}\right)^{2} &\\
                            &= (x-y)^{2} -4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )^{2}\right) + 4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}((x-y)\cdot u_{i} )^{2}\right) &\\
                            &= (x-y)^{2} &= d(x,y)^2
      \end{array}$$

Notice that the third to last equality only holds because the $u_i$ form an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 2):

Pick an origin for $\Bbb E^n$, and call the resulting vector space $\Bbb R^n$. To save notation, let's put the origin in $S$, so that $S$ now becomes a (vector) subspace. Write $\Bbb R^n=S\oplus S^\perp$. Now, identifying points $x\in\Bbb E^n$ with the corresponding vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, write $x=x_1+x_2$, where $x_1\in S$ and $x_2\in S^\perp$. Then $\pi_S(x)=x_1$ and $x-\pi_S(x) = x_2\in S^\perp$.

Here's a lemma you need to prove, using dot products. (It's just a higher-dimensional Pythagorean Theorem.)

**Lemma**: Writing $x=x_1+x_2$, $x_1\in S$, $x_2\in S^\perp$, we have $\|x\|^2 = \|x_1\|^2 + \|x_2\|^2$.

The vector $\overrightarrow{x\pi_S(x)}$ can now be written as $\pi_S(x)-x=-x_2$, so our formula for $R_S$ becomes $R_S(x) = (x_1+x_2)+2(-x_2)= x_1-x_2$. Now it's clear that for any $x,y\in\Bbb R^n$, we have
$$R_S(x)-R_S(y) = (x_1-x_2)-(y_1-y_2) = (x_1-y_1) + (y_2-x_2).$$
Because $x_1-y_1\in S$ and $y_2-x_2\in S^\perp$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\|R_S(x)-R_S(y)\|^2 &= \|x_1-y_1\|^2 + \|y_2-x_2\|^2 = \|x_1-y_1\|^2 + \|x_2-y_2\|^2 \\&= \|(x_1+x_2)-(y_1+y_2)\|^2 = \|x-y\|^2,
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Again, thanks, but S is not a linear subspace, it's an affine subspace. Equally so, a point is not just a vector. It's a point.

Comment: @SydKerckhove The definition of affine space requires that the entire space is able to be identified with a certain vector space, by assigning an origin. Once you have done this it's perfectly licit to carry on as if your points were vectors, as long as you don't change the origin along the way.

Comment: The entire point (haha, get it...) of affine spaces is that you don't need an origin. The (internal) addition of points is not defined. There is only the sum of a point and a vector, and the difference between two points which is a vector.

Comment: @Syd: Yes, I know all that. But the point of affine geometry is that there *is* underlying vector algebra as well.

Comment: @SydKerckhove `...is that you don't need an origin`. I wouldn't say that. What I'd say is that, in contrast to a vector space, there is no $distinguished$ point or $0$ that we always identify as the origin. Any point can have this role and the inherent structure won't change. You can of course, work without ever naming an origin, but why would you if it simplifies calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer which is suitable for Euclidean space (not quite as general as an affine space).  Given a vector $a$ in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, the formula for the reflection in the hyperplane through the origin, orthogonal to $a$, is given by

$$\text{Ref}_a(v) = v - 2\frac{v\cdot a}{a\cdot a}a$$

Recall that the distance between two vectors $v$ and $w$ is $d(v,w)=|v-w|$.  So we can show that

$$d(\text{Ref}_a(v),\text{Ref}_a(w))=| v - 2\frac{v\cdot a}{a\cdot a}a - (w - 2\frac{w\cdot a}{a\cdot a}a)| = |v-w+2(wa-va)\frac{a}{a\cdot a}| = $$

$$=|v-w+2(w-v)\frac{a\cdot a}{a\cdot a}|=d(v,w)$$

Comment: Distance isn't even defined in arbitrary affine spaces so I think this is quite suitable.

Comment: Pardon me.... are you saying this is unsuitable or suitable?

Comment: In any case, I said it was a "partial answer", it was too long to be a comment and I am hoping that it will give some insight.

Comment: Well I meant suitable originally, because once you don't actually lose generality by saying "Euclidean Space" because the term "isometry" only applies in Euclidean Spaces anyway. On second glance though I noticed this only covers the hyperplane case.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but in this instance, I don't get how you can stick to just using vectors and no points.
In my definition, the reflection is defined on points, not vectors.